# How can an inherited copyright be released under a Creative Commons license?

Tags: united-states, copyright, creative-commons, inheritance

Alice created a work and died without publishing it. Bob and Charlie jointly inherited the copyright. Bob wants to release it under a Creative Commons license without involving Charlie. Can he do this? If so, how?

Comment: I think this is more of a law question than a free software one.  I know some jurisdictions have the concepts of *ownership in joint* and *ownership in common*, one being where either party may unilaterally dispose of half the asset, the other being where the asset may only be disposed of whole, and only under the consent of both parties.  How copyright as a shared legacy is regarded will be jurisdictionally-dependent, and may also depend on how the will was written.  None of those issues is really a free software one.  Would you like me to transfer this question to law.SE?

Comment: @MadHatter I think it would probably be closed as an RSLA there, but if it's off-topic here, then sure, you can migrate it and we'll see how it's received there. Thank you!

Comment: I'll wait a bit for the community to express an opinion.  If it  starts attracting downvotes or close votes, I'll think about throwing it across the fence.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that if the answer would remain unchanged if you replace every instance of an open source specific term in a question with a non-open source term, then the question is probably off-topic here because it's not really about open source; hence I’m voting to close this question because I could replace "Creative Commons" with "Proprietary License 13".

Comment: I think it is clearly off topic here, this question is about inheritance law, which is likely specific to the jurisdiction governing Alice's copyright, and about copyright law (jurisdiction specific) w.r.t. governance of joint/shared ownership of copyright by Bob and Charlie.

Comment: @MadHatter now that this has been migrated back to Law, it's a duplicate of a previous question that I asked: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/81204/what-happens-if-multiple-people-inherit-a-copyright I see that it was also edited to not ask specifically about Creative Commons licenses. What I was originally asking was how a Creative Commons license would be applied - that is, how the copyright notice for those specific licenses should be written in this case. Changing it to refer to licenses in general does make it a substantially different question, because there are standard...

Comment: ...copyright notices used for CC licenses, and I am asking how to adapt those to this situation. That's probably off-topic here as an RSLA, and I believe it is on-topic on Open Source SE because it is specifically about CC licenses? The only part of the question that I think is on-topic here is the part asking whether this can be done, which is probably a duplicate of the question I linked earlier.

Comment: (also pinging @PhilipKendall)

Comment: @Someone I can't agree that it's a "*substantially different question*".  If Bob has the right to unilaterally license the code, he may do so under any licence he wants.  If he doesn't, there is nothing special about CC licences that will let him do it without that right.  The choice of licence is not material to the question, which is about whether Bob has the right to unilaterally licence the code.  If what you wanted to ask is "*how does Bob licence code under CC when he has the rights to do so*", that would be on-topic for OS.SE, but the inheritance stuff needs to be removed.

Comment: @MadHatter that is my question. "Bob has the right to license code under CC, but he is not the author. How should he write the copyright notice?"

Comment: "Alice created a work and died without publishing it. Bob and Charlie jointly inherited the copyright." This, Bob, under US law, has the right to license the software. "Bob wants to release it under a Creative Commons license without involving Charlie. Can he do this?" I know he can license it, but I want to make sure there's not something specific to Creative Commons that's an issue, such as a clause in the license that requires the agreement of all copyright holders. "If so, how?" Since the copyright and license notice is what puts a work under CC, this is asking how to write the notice.

Comment: I don't understand why you think Bob has the right to licence it, but also doesn't.  Actually, I don't know why you think he does, but I don't know much about US law.  I don't think he has the right in England and Wales, because he's not the sole rightsholder, though that might be wrong, too.  But the greater point stands: if he has the right, he may license under any licence he chooses.  If he doesn't, he may not, and no choice of licence will magically give him that right.  The fact that he's not the author is immaterial, as long as he holds the copyright.  This isn't a free software issue.

Comment: @MadHatter In the US, one copyright holder can issue a non-exclusive license: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/81204/what-happens-if-multiple-people-inherit-a-copyright The reason I'm asking specifically whether he can grant a CC license is that it's possible, although unlikely, that something in the CC licenses either makes them considered "exclusive" in some way, or explicitly state that all copyright holders must agree. This is specific to Creative Commons licenses, so I believe it is on-topic on Open Source and off-topic here on Law. Assuming he is allowed to grant the license...

Comment: ...the next part of my question asks how he can do it - that is, how he can write the copyright and license notice, for a Creative Commons license.

Comment: That makes more sense, but **you didn't put any of that in the original question**.  If you wanted to post a new question, linking to the earlier answer on Law, and being clear that what you wanted to know is whether someone who inherits a partial share of a copyright can licence under a **specific** free licence, and being clear that your question was US-specific, then I'd (personally) feel that the question was likely on-topic for OS.SE.  I can't say whether the community would agree, but I think you'd have a chance.

Comment: @MadHatter I posted a new question on OSSE: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/14636/can-one-of-several-heirs-of-a-copyright-release-it-under-a-creative-commons-lice